# How create channel to read a BLOB and write file system file

Tags: mirth

I am trying to create a image by fetching blob from MySQL DB ...
 Here goes the code....

```
var dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname','username','');

var query_code = "Select blob from tblname where id =59"; // 

var result = dbConn.executeCachedQuery(query_code);
dbConn.close();


if (result.next())
{   
    var image=FileUtil.encode(result.getBytes(1));
    $gc('image1', image);    
}
```

Could anyone help me out to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

Did You receive any error with this code if so post it.
Im not sure with Mirth connect tool But as far as I know, Retrieving the BLOB image from the DB directly with any IDE/Tools is always possible but difficult with 2 ways

1. By encoding to BASE-64 charcter
2. By specifying the entire location saving  it locally.
   And try removing the dbconn.close(); do not use it or use it after if() statement. Because it will throw an error like "no statements were executed after dbconn.close();